# Как делаются такие косые блоки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал искать в гугле, но там какие-то непонятные методы, если делать через skew то текст становится нечитабельным, либо я что-то не так делаю.

```css
div {
  margin: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  right: -100px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Вложенные блоки, один skew 30grad, второй минус 30grad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так, без вложенных блоков на псевдоэлементах со `skew`:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: teal;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div>StackOverflow</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper_one {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 170px;
  height: 26px;
}

.one {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
}

.one:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000; 
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
}

.one:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  border-left: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 13px solid #000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_one">
  <div class="one">LED POWER STYLE</div>
</div>
```